# Tabla dentro de un modal, no se me hace resposive Datatable

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Estoy intentando hacer para que mi tabla sea resposive, estoy utilizando datatable pero no se porque, pongo la opcion de resposive:true y no se me hace resposive.

```
function cargarDataGrid(rutaJsonIdioma){
    $('#hojas_resumen').DataTable({
           "order": [9,'asc'],     // Desactiva orden inicial para mostrar datos según orden de consulta SQL
           "info": true,
           "searching": true, 
           "paging":   true,
           "responsive": true,
           "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
                mosrarDataGrid();
            },
                columnDefs: [{
                className: 'control',
                orderable: true,
            }],
                "language": {
                "url": rutaJsonIdioma
           },
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola Pol y bienvenido a la comunidad de stackoverflow **en español**. Por favor, ¿podrías redactar la pregunta en castellano? Gracias.

Comment: Ten en cuenta de que a tu etiqueta  `table` le tienes que añadir unas clases tambien. [Link](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/init)

Comment: Ya lo tengo puesto y ni a un asi se me hace resposive.